# make dropdown push elements down the page

Tags: jquery, css

is it possible to make a dropdown push down the elements underneath it when you click to see the options, and then when you "close" the dropdown for the elements to get back to the initial position?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you want to do this?  It's seem a bit odd.  You might want take a look at some accordion control and modify it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. in the end I did it by wrapping a div around it and changing the height of the div on mouse click.

Comment: what you need is actually a tab based menu that collapse when mouseout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for the suggestion. in the end I did it by wrapping a div around it and changing the height of the div on mouse click.